# Feynman diagram literature for antiproton production via proton-proton collisions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, antimatter, protons

I'm looking for literature, or anywhere I can find a Feynman diagram, which describes the proton-proton collision where antiprotons are produced in the following reaction:
$$\rm{p} + \rm{p} \rightarrow \rm{p} + \rm{p} + \rm{p} + \bar{\rm{p}}$$
I'm sure there are MANY possible production channels, I just want an example and ideally a reviewed sourced to cite. So far the only anitproton production Feynman diagrams I can find are from two-photon interactions.

I have found literature which discusses such a reaction, but with no Feynman diagram [here](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.94.499).

---

I had a good comment that questioned my energy regime, given that there are different convention for drawing Feynman diagrams which depend on this. The minimum energy requirement for the reaction, described by the equation above, is $6$ $\rm{GeV}$.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to draw individual channels? Or even ennumerate them? Opperationally we just create hadronic jets and filter what comes out; there is no reliance on the detailed mechanism.

Comment: Sure. But when writting about a topic I find it jolly to show at least one example of a process, even if that example is not exhaustive. I agree that the exact processes of such interactions are not that useful in most cases.

Comment: Whenever you consider a hadronic interaction, there are two kinds of Feynman diagrams you can draw, either in terms of quarks and gluons (more appropriate at high energy), or baryons and mesons (relevant at low energy). What are you looking for?

Comment: @Thomas A fair point. Well the minimum energy for this reaction is around $6$ $\rm{GeV}$. I don't know what is classified as low energy. Anything between $6-30$ $\rm{GeV}$ would be reasonable.

Comment: Are you interested in processes that actually happen, or just something that looks right? If it's the latter, it's not hard to just draw something that follows the rules.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Preferably I am looking for a paper that has looked into this. I would like something citable. It doesn't need to be exhaustive. However in the absense of this I will accept as you propose, but I could just as well draw this myself. The real point is looking for a citable source.

Comment: Six GeV is smack in the middle of the the transition region. Too low for purturbative convergence in any reasonable number of terms, but high enough that QCD effects are non-trivial and you can't pretend that QHD is a viable theory. $30\,\mathrm{GeV}$ is rather closer to "high energy".

Comment: @dmckee well let's take the high energy case. It is probably more relatable to my discussion in any event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to find my own answer by consulting the [original paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.100.947) by Chamberlain et al. and looking at the rerences there in. If one looks at the references in this paper, in the work of [Feldman](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.95.1697) there is a Feynman digarm describing the process of antiproton production.